# Install program. Check files in the folder then kill process

Tags: powershell

I have a program which needs to be installed silently. But it doesn't stop the process at the end (because of window - need to press OK). So I need to:

1. Check if the folder exists
2. Start the installation of the program and wait for ~15 seconds
3. Then I need to check one of the files in this folder of the program
4. If it exists I should kill the process of installation (if not go to 1.)

So I have two script blocks. How can I realize it to one script block or maybe function?

```
if (-not(Test-Path $folder)) { 
    Start-Process $program /S
} else {
    Write-Output "Program is already installed"
}

if (Test-Path $file) { 
    Stop-Process -Name "Install program*"
} else {
    Write-Output "Program is already installed"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the second conditional in the "then" branch of the first one, assign the installer process object to a variable, add a sleep after starting the process, and kill the process via the process object.

```
if (-not(Test-Path $folder)) { 
    $p = Start-Process $program /S -PassThru
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
    if (Test-Path $file) { 
        $p.Kill()
    } else {
        Write-Output "Program is already installed"
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "Program is already installed"
}
```